# переназначить id

Tags: php, mysql, json

Всем добрый день!

Есть три таблицы в базе данных.

В первой лежат `persons`, во второй `services`, в третьей отношение МкМ `services_to_persons`.

Персоны имеют уникальный `id` который повышается как `auto_increment`. То же самое с `services`.

В `services_to_persons` лежат соотношения персон к сервисам.
При этом к одному сервису может быть прикреплено множество персон и наоборот.

Я беру данные из БД, формирую `json` и отправляю в `API`.

Внутри `json` есть несколько массивов - в первом указанны все персоны в виде `id` + ФИО, во втором указанны все сервисы, а привязанные к ним гости указываются как подмассив `id` персон.

И все было бы здорово и хорошо работало, но тут оказалось, что внутри json `id` массива `persons` но может превышать 999. А из БД получаются куда как большие значения.

И задача, которая встала передо мной - переназначить `id` для массива персон, после получения из БД, и до создания `json`. И чего-то мне никак не приходит в голову, какой бы хитростью, что бы не писать громоздких циклов это сделать.

Может как-то на моменте получения из БД, сразу пересобрать массив `persons`?

**UPD**

> На данный момент сделал такое решение - при получении из БД массива
>   `persons` назначаю им новые `id`, а потом при записи в массив
>   `services->guests` просто при помощи `if` сравниваю `id` из БД, со
>   старым `id` персон из БД. Но это получается все же какой-то индусский
>   код. Может есть более элегантные решения?

Comment: нет, задачу мне поставили, что числа `id` должны быть в диапазоне от 1-999. Почему не знаю, просто такое требование.

Comment: Тогда заведите отдельное поле "id для json", и его спокойно пересчитывайте. Причем держать его надо только в persons, при выдаче массивов связок с сервисами делаете join и отправляете эти же id. А перечет на лету приведет к куче проблем, в виде "отправили персоны, в этот момент что то удалили, нумерация сбилась, а клиент запросил массив связей с сервисами ..."

Comment: @Mike, т.е. просто в таблице `persons` держать доп.поле, которое не может превышать 999?

Comment: Да, при удалении записей с ним ничего не делать, но при добавлении брать первый свободный номер. Хотя в идеале я бы конечно их каким нибудь кольцевым алгоритмом назначал, что бы id только что удаленных записей некоторое время никому не назначались. Я же на знаю что у вас клиент делает после получения этого json. А то ведь он небось к вам потом какие нибудь запросы шлет, опираясь на эти id и может оказаться, что он возьмет список, а через минуту обратиться, а к этому времени уже что то удалили и что то добавили в person и id новой записи совпадет с той, под которой кто то старый был ...

Comment: В общем в любом случае ожидается куча ненужной головной боли с этими "id" и правильным решением, как сказал @Drakonoved было бы убедить заказчика так не делать

Comment: Похоже просто кто-то написал «парсер» для JSON

Answer (score 0):

Из комментария:

В любом случае ожидается куча ненужной головной боли с этими "id", и правильным решением было бы убедить заказчика так не делать.